# Meaning of "up" and "off" in "I live up north off some_region"

Tags: prepositions, toponyms

I am only familiar with sentences like

> I live in New York
>       I live on the north side of New York

I guess

> I live up north off some_region.

means the place I live in is a little bit northern than *some_region*.

Do the following sentences make sense, too and mean the same thing?

> I live north off some_region.
>       I live up north of some_region.
>       I live north of some_region.

Comment: this is more ELL dude

Answer (score -1):

"off" is **COMPLETELY WRONG** in the **EXAMPLES YOU GIVE**. it's just a typo.

It should be "of."  So, north of, south of, east of, west of.

I live north of Montana.

---

(The "up" is irrelevant. It's just a colloquialism.  You can add it if you want: "I live up north of Montana" or "I live down south of Texas".)

---

**Note that** the word **off** can be used to mean: **NEAR SOMETHING**.

This is totally unrelated.

So, "I live off the highway" (I live just near the highway), "The boat is off the coast." (it's near the coast).

Comment: Not completely. It could have a reason to be there, sometimes.

Comment: You're totally wrong, Kris.  If you have an example - let's hear it!!

Comment: (If you mean "I live North. Off the coast." Note that I gave that examples and explained it?  Is that what you're referring to?)

Comment: In nautical terms you might say "We fished in international waters North off West Greenland."  Or when discussing road directions one might say, "2 miles North off US 17 on Charleston Harbor in Mt. Pleasant."

Comment: Right, those are the exact examples I gave in my answer, of it being **a separate clause**.  (Did you not read my answer? it's very short :) )  Simply read the OPs question to see the correct answer.

Comment: Note that you need commas in your two examples there.

Comment: @JoeBlow Thank you but.. I am confused as to when I choose off and when of.  Lumberjack's example has "north off". Why is it correct while my two examples are incorrect?

Comment: Hi user!  **"off" is COMPLETELY WRONG in the two examples you give**  OK?  It's that simple.  "north of" is a phrase.  it's just "of" ..north of, south of.  You only use "off" in very unusual situations, with no connection at all to "north".  It means "nearby".  For example, you could say "I live off Highway-31" which simply means "near" Highway-31.  There is utterly no connection to when you say "north of" or "south of". It's a completely different word.

Comment: Lumberjack's example is incredibly wrong.  It's supposed to be a new sentence.  "Two miles North. Off Highway 17."  (or a comma: "Two miles North, off Highway 17."

Comment: If you live down south of Texas, why not just say, “I live in Mexico”? ;-)

Comment: Now that's funny - but as long as you're here pls help tell User what "of" and "off" means!  :)